# How to enable Salesforce File Sync?

Tags: chatter, files

I have been trying to enable how to Salesforce File sync in my Salesforce developer org but with no success. Things what all I tried so far:
Navigate to Setup -> Chatter -> Setting but there was no option to file sync. What should I do now. I can not even raise a case at salesforce as I have Developer Org. What should I do?

Comment: Can you change question to phrase it as a question? For example, How to enable Salesforce File Sync. Ah, looks like I can do it myself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two settings that need checked.

1) Enable Files Sync mentioned above. However, the UI has changed a tiny bit.

Here is where I found it:

**Setup > Build > Customize > Salesforce Files > Settings > General Settings** and then there is an “**Enable Files Sync**” checkbox.

2) Once you check it, a new permission appears on the profiles, **Sync Files**.

With those two checked, the client executable appears in the list under Desktop Add-Ons. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking is in this navigation.

Navigate to **Setup** | **Customize** | **Salesforce Files** | **Settings** > Salesforce File Sync

And **Enable** it by click on "Edit" button.

See image below:

[image]

If you want to sync from Desktop then you can navigate to **Setup** | **Personal Setup** | **Desktop Integration** > Salesforce File Sync

[image]

Comment: I did enable it but still I can not download it. I need to sync my desktop files with salesforce.  After enabling file sync I even tried to navigate to Chatter Setting & find for File Sync option but with no success.

Comment: @guest610 you need to download utility in Desktop integration section. Navigation is given in last two lines of answer.

Comment: I did navigate to that setup but I could not find any Salesforce File Sync Option to download it for desktop. I am unable to add attach the  screenshot for reference.

Comment: @guest610 updated with screenshot of my dev. Download url for me is http://na11.salesforce.com/setup/salesforcefilesync/win/SalesforceFilesInstaller.exe

Comment: Thanks it helped me download it but i could not sync it. I checked for all settings. But my desktop & org still not synced